# syntaxhighlighter -- how to add the optional language pack to standard version

Tags: syntaxhighlighter

The standard version of syntaxhighlighter 3.0.83 ( http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/download/ ) is similar to the plugin for Wordpress which contains an optional language pack ( http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-syntaxhighlighter/ ) -- e.g., Biferno, Clojure, DOS batch file, F#, LISP, Lua (only for SyntaxHighlighter 3.0), MEL Script, Objective-C, PowerCLI, Processing, R, S, S-PLUS, Tcl, Verilog, Vim Script and YAML.  I'm looking for a way to add the optional languages to the standard version -- any assistance in that regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Download the Wordpress plugin from:  http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-syntaxhighlighter/  As of the date of this answer, the most recent version was `wp-syntaxhighlighter.1.7.3.zip`
- Extract the `*.js` and `*.css` files from the subfolders within the folder `lang-pack-for-wp-syntaxhighlighter` and organize them to your liking.  In my case, I chose to place the `*.js` language files inside the folder `syntaxhighlighter/scripts/` in the standard version.  There was only one `*.css` file -- i.e., `shBrushProcessing.css` and I chose to place that inside the folder `syntaxhighlighter/styles/` in the standard version.
- In your `*.html` file, ensure the path to the brush javascript file is correct -- e.g., for `lisp` use:

  `<script type="text/javascript" src="syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shBrushLisp.js"></script>`
- In your `*.html` file, the brush must correspond to the brush javascript file -- e.g., for `lisp`use:

  `<pre class="brush:  lisp">`